# How can I search my own questions?

Tags: support, search

I've asked more than my share of questions.  And sometimes, I want to do something and I know I asked it on SO, but can't remember it.

Is there a specific syntax for searching just my own questions?
The reason I am asking is that when I do general searching, I get a lot of noise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for:

```
user:9382
```

(or whatever user id)

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I needed.

Comment: But that gives also the questions that i've answered. What if i want to get my questions only? Edit: i've found out myself: `user:me  is:question`

Answer (score 10):

**SUPER NINJA SPECIAL SEARCH OPTION** - Search by particular user

Use the syntax "user:[UserID]"

**Example**: user:22164

For the vainglorious searches on your own post, you can use the clipped shorthand:

> [user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me)

Other Special Search Options can be found here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 5):

You can concat the search options mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

To get only your questions:

```
user:me  is:question
```