# Stackoverflow: How to search own questions

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/how-can-i-search-my-own-questions)

How can I search my own questions in Stackoverflow?

Comment: And now its fairly blatantly a duplicate of several e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/how-can-i-search-my-own-questions but there are several more in "related"

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page.  You're probably looking for `user:me <keyword(s) you want to find in your questions>`.

Comment: Search tips page is available by entering the search box and pressing enter when the box is empty

Answer (score 0):

Click on your name at the top next to your score/rating.  It will show all your questions and answers you've provided to others.

Comment: @DRapp: If you look at OP's questions, he has 39 pages (wow!)...he's asking how to *search* them.