# How to search in my questions?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/how-can-i-search-my-own-questions)

Is there a possibility to do a search in only my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, search for:

```
user:me <other search terms>
```