# Possible to make own questions searchable?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25176/how-can-i-search-my-own-questions)

Not sure this has been asked before (can't find anything on it), but I often find myself looking for a question I asked some time ago and for which I want to re-check the answer I received.

This can be a real pain, because there is no way to search asked questions across the paginated list, so if I'm looking for `vhost` I can use the browser search, but I need to do it one every paginated page and keep my fingers crossed my former question title was close enough (I wrote `custom-url` in my `vhost` question, so I will not find it like this).

So my feature request would be for a `search field for own questions asked`, `fulltext` or at least `title` and `tags`.